# Was Shechem a gilgul of Eisav?

Tags: rashi, yosef, yaakov-and-eisav

The Arizal says (she'ar Hagilgulim) that it's not a problem that Shem and Noach were the same gilgul, although they were father and son, alive at the same time.

In Breshit 48:22  Ya'akov Avinu says he took Shechem from the hand of the Amorite, **who Rashi identifies as Eisav**, who was still alive.We know that Shechem himself was killed, and his land was given to Yosef by Yaakov avinu.

22. "And I have given you one portion over your brothers, which I took from the hand of The Amorite with my sword and with my bow."
    Rashi: [Shechem] one portion over your brothers: Heb. אַחַד עַל אַחֶי‏ שְׁכֶם, **the actual [city of] Shechem**, which will be for you one share over your brothers.

Rashi: **which I took from the hand of the Amorite**: **From the hand of Esau**, who behaved like an Amorite (Gen. Rabbah 97:6). Another explanation [of why Esau is called אמֹרִי]: who deceived his father with the sayings (אִמְרֵי) of his mouth.

So was Shechem was a (at least a partial) gilgul of Eisav?

Comment: Which part of this is from the Arizal? It would be helpful to include a link.

Comment: Looks like it's [here](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%93). He doesn't mention anything about Shechem and Eisav. What makes you think he was a gilgul?

Comment: It's just a hunch. Yaakov said that he took Shechem from Eisav. It just seems like there may be more to it than what is explicitly written.

Comment: אל תתמה, איך נח ושם היו יחד בזמן א', עם היותם בחי' אחת(about them being comtemporaries)

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Moshe and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: One potential problem with a gilgul living at the same time as the original person : the gilgul might meet the person and influence the person in a way which obviates the necessity of the gilgul. For example, if the gilgul came down to rectify some sin of that person, the gilgul might prevent the person from sinning, and so then it would be contradictory for the gilgul to have been created in the first place.

Comment: Or to put it another way, the existence of the gilgul seems to take away the free will of the original person. It implies that no matter what future actions that person takes in his lifetime, there will still be a need for a gilgul. Granted, the original might never find out about the existence of his contemporaneous gilgul, but in theory he could (there are accounts of people being able to find out who they are a gilgul of and why).

Comment: Here is another reason why I believe there is reason to suggest this idea:  Besides the fact that Rashi says Yaakov took Shechem from Eisav (the Amori), Says Bereshit Rabba 76:9: Hashem said, "You refused to give your daughter (Dinah) to your circumcised brother (Aisav). Now worse will befall you! She will be taken by an uncircumcised man!"
לֹא בִקַּשְׁתָּ לְהַשִֹּׂיאָהּ לְמָהוּל הֲרֵי הִיא נִשֵֹּׂאת לְעָרֵל, לֹא בִקַּשְׁתָּ לְהַשִֹּׂיאָהּ דֶּרֶךְ הֶתֵּר הֲרֵי נִשֵֹּׂאת דֶּרֶךְ אִסּוּר, הֲדָא הוּא דִכְתִיב (בראשית לד, א): וַתֵּצֵא דִינָה בַּת לֵאָה

Comment: It is important to understand the concept of gilgul outlined here. Eisav was an actual son (a descendant of) Yitzchok Avinu. His relationship to the Amorites, who are actual descendants from Kayin, was only by being influenced from their behaviors & practices (like the prohibition to not follow their ways). That disconnects him from the influence/inheritance of his father, Yitzchok Avinu.

Comment: Concerning this subject, see Rashi to Bereshit 32:23.

Comment: So the “gilgul” idea here or “transformation”, meaning “mutation” (השתנות) only pertains to external behavior and not to the root of the soul.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple parts of the soul. And a complete set can be spread amongst multiple people. It could be that Eisav and Shechem had soul pieces that belonged together. Perhaps Shechem and Dinah's daughter were supposed to marry Elifaz or something like that to unite them.

Comment: This answer underlines that you don't really understand what gilgul is about. The soul doesn't have "parts", like Rambam explains in Moreh Nevuchim on this subject. A soul can branch, like the flow of water branches, but it remains one, connected. Eisav is the son of Yitzchok (1st to be circumcised on the 8th day by covenant), descendant of Adam (born circumcised). Shechem, as far as I have looked at this, is a descendant of the Amorite nation which were a branch of the peoples who existed prior to Adam HaRishon and who were the father to Kayin. None were circumcised.

Comment: Eisav and Shechem were circumcised. Shechem is a hivite, and thus a regular person, descnded from Adam. As for the parts, it's part of the Chassidic realm of thought.

Comment: The Chivi at the time of Shechem were also from Kayin. The “Nachash” who impregnated Chava was a Chivite. See Targum Onkelos to Bereshit there. There were 10 pre-Adam lines of mankind spread across the globe. Shechem was not part of the circumcised line until compelled to by the children of Yaacov Avinu.

Comment: So is Shechem not descended from Noah? He wasn't forced to circumcise, but he did voluntarily.

Comment: Submission is not necessarily “voluntary”. He wanted Dina. Regarding the subject of those remnants of the pre-humans who survived the flood, there are many examples of apparent survivors. Think of Og and Goliath, for example.

Answer (score -1):

Gilgul doesn't have to mean actual 1:1 reincarnation. It is said that Shechem's taking of Dinah was a punishment for withholding her from Eisav.

Shechem and Eisav were gilgul in the sense that they were the same kind of person even if they weren't factually the same person.

Comment: MosheSF is only speculating that perhaps the concept of Gilgul HaNeshamot applies to the discussion Eisav and Shechem. You appear to be trying to present the idea I mentioned in my comments to Moshe, but with no sources to support what you are writing and not really explaining it well. Gilgul is not the best term to use to convey what Rashi is explaining even though technically it is a synonym for "transformation" and "mutation". This answer needs work.

Comment: Actually, I put my answer in before your comment. As for explanations, we don't have hard and fast rules for how gilgulim work.

Comment: If you want to stand with the answer you presented, that’s your choice. You should look at the Mi Yodeya section discussing what makes a good answer. I’m trying to help you.